# Query operation approach slow

Tags: php, mysql

I am having performance issues with this application. Basically i have three tables:

> tblmembers: memberid,memberemail
>   tbltalks:talkid,talkdate,talknote
>   tblmemberstalks: id,memberid,talkid

Table members contains list of members
Table calls stores list of speaking/conference talks
Table memberstalks stores list of members who will speak at a particular conference.

Now from my front end (CMS), I want to manage who will speak in a conference (add/remove members). There are currently 1009 members. In current approach I am getting first list of members who are registered to speak at a conference so they can be removed and another query to get list of members who are not yet added as speakers so they can registered.

Essentially, I am going through the members table and checking `tblmemberstalks` for each member. Is there any better way to improve because the number of participants will increase gradually.

```
$registered="SELECT memberid,memberemail from tblmembers WHERE memberid IN (SELECT memberid FROM tblmemberstalks where talkid=1)";
$unregisterd="SELECT memberid,memberemail from tblmembers WHERE memberid NOT IN (SELECT memberid FROM tblmemberstalks where talkid=1)";
```

Answer (score 0):

> USE LEFT JOIN WITH CONDITION AND CHECK THE NULL ENTRY FOR UNREGISTRED

```
SELECT 
case when mt.memberid is not null then 'registered' else 'not-registered' end as registration_status,
m.memberemail 

from tblmembers m
LEFT JOIN tblmemberstalks mt ON (mt.member_id=m.id AND mt.talkid=1)
```